# Inserting Chart from another Workbook as image into a Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Macro-enabled Excel 2010 Workbook ("Pilote.xlsm") that tries to read into multiple Excel workbook ("Ex01.xlsx", "Ex02.xlsx", ...) and copy a Charts ("Target") into a Word Document while keeping the same orientation ("portrait").

It seems that it is not possible to do that the way I've tried. Code sample follow :

```
Function BasicWrite()
Dim MonWB As Workbook
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add()
Set monWB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\foo\Ex01.xlsx")

wrdApp.Visible = True

wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="VBA"
wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

monWB.Activate
monWB.Charts("Target").CopyPicture

wrdApp.Selection.Paste

monWB.Close
End Function
```

This results in the correct charts copied in the Word document, although in "landscape" (width > height) whereas the original chart is "portrait" (height > width). This change messes some important labels that are on the Chart.

This orientation problem does not happen when I copy a chart directly from the Macro workbook ("Pilote.xlsm") into the Word document. It seems to be an artifact from copying from an external ("Ex01.xlsx") workbook. I failed to find any information regarding this topic in the documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some simple steps that reproduce this? It's not clear how these charts get into the various workbooks, so that they're different in one than in another. These are charts *sheets*, not chart objects on a worksheet?

Comment: @CindyMeister : "Ex01.xlsx", "Ex02.xlsx", ... are all generated using the same unrelated Excel macro. All the charts share the same characteristics. The charts I'm trying to copy are charts sheets. I tried to copy one of these charts sheets into the macro I'm trying to get working ("Pilote.xlsm"), using right click > copy or move, and then running the macro so that it would copy the charts inside "Pilote.xlsm" into the word document.